# c++ 11 which feature implemented in which compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, c++11

I need to write code that should be compiled in visual studio and gcc. I am looking in some interesting features such as strongly typed enumerator and static_assert, but I am not sure if they are supported in visual studio and/or gcc and if they are supported in which version of these compilers.

Is there any documentation which lists the details of each c++11 standard implementation for different visual studio or gcc compilers? If there isn't, we can start a thread to list them.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: There is an overview at apache.org: [C++0xCompilerSupport](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) also check [C++11/14 compiler and library shootout](http://cpprocks.com/c1114-compiler-and-library-shootout/)

Comment: Doesn't matter - they're all broken anyway :)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x

Comment: In all seriousness, though, is there any justification for not upgrading to the most recent version?

Comment: @Brian: In the enterprise world ? The bigger the code base, the more justifications there are.

Comment: Martin James' comment was a bit sarcastic, however it does have a point. Unfortunately many compilers declared their compliance at a time their implementation was still limited or suffered bugs; over time those are culled, however there is no telling whether you will hit them or not. The best advice we might offer at this point is to try...